# Is it possible to remove the start of a sum of a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Normally, you would do [1:] or [:1] to remove the front or end of a string but if I have value 1 and value 2, sum it up and try to remove, it doesn't work.

Code:

```
v1 = 14831.1001
v2 = 28483.4782

sum = v1 + v2

print(sum[1:])
```

Comment: No, you cannot do like that. You have to convert it to a string

Comment: try this `float(str(sum)[1:])`

Comment: Please don't use in-built functions as variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you will try to print the sum you will get this error.

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

You will get this error when you try to access the float digit as if they are indexed which is incorrect. You need to explicitly typecast the sum to string, in order to get your required results. Below code will work:

```
print(str(sum)[1:])
```

Comment: Please avoid the use of inbuilt functions as variables even though OP has used it